# How calculate number hours between two datetime field odoo 9

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

How calculate hours in my example:

((FINISH - START) - PAUSE)

**format in form view**

start = 02/10/2017 07:55:54

finish = 02/10/2017 16:50:54

pause = 1 hour (default)

---

in console datetime look like this: 2017-02-10 07:55:54

**Need this   ==> result = 07:55**

```
How in @api.depends('start', 'finish') 
    def calculate_hours(self):
        #
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use timedelta or relative delta to calculate the difference. Before that, you have to convert to datetime object. Here's how I would do

```
from openerp import api, fields
# if use relativedelta 
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta 


@api.depends('start', 'finish')
def calculate_hours(self):
  for record in self:
    start_dt = fields.Datetime.from_string(record.start)
    finish_dt = fields.Datetime.from_string(record.finish)

    # using relativedelta 
    # pause time = 1, you could change to the number you desire. 
    pause = relativedelta(hours=1)
    difference = relativedelta(finish_dt, start_dt) - pause 
    # from relative delta you could get hours or minutes as you wanted 
    # hours = difference.hours 
    # minutes = difference.minutes 

    # using timedelta 
    # pause = timedelta(seconds=3600)
    # difference = finish_dt - start_dt - pause
    # first element of timedelta is days, if you want to calculate the difference of days in hours, add difference.days * 24  
    # hours = int(difference.seconds/3600)
    # minutes = (difference.seconds % 3600) / 60
    # your code ....
```

Hope my answer meets your requirements.

Comment: Nice example, please is it possible put example for timedelta. GL

Comment: yes of course, I edited the answer to show how to use timedelta.